# Using QGIS Temporal Controller with Mapserver WMS-T

Tags: qgis-3, wms-time, temporal-controller

I have defined a WMS-T (WMS + Time) service of GeoTiff files that is working with TimeManager (QGIS 3.4).
The same WMS-T service doesn't work with TemporalController (QGIS 3.16).
TemporalController doesn't through any error but doesn't show any image.

Testing WMS-T service with GetMap request in web browser with different values of TIME parameter return correct images, so the WMS-T service is working fine.

With TimeManager (QGIS 3.4) I set datetime format to `%Y` but with TemporalController (QGIS 3.16) I cannot find this option. I have trying different datetime formats like this `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'` but TemporalController doesn't work.

To be more precise, I have this code in mapserver configuration file (.map):

```
LAYER
        NAME "temporal_serie_raster"
        TYPE RASTER
        STATUS ON

        METADATA
            "wms_title"             "metadata_layer_title"
            "wms_abstract"          "metadata_layer_abstract"
            "ows_extent"            "metadata_layer_extent"
            "ows_srs"               "metadata_layer_srslist"
            "ows_keywordlist"       "metadata_layer_keywordlist"
            

            "wms_timeextent"    "2017/2020"
            "wms_timeitem"      "time"
            "wms_timeformat"    "YYYY"
        END # Metadata
        
        TILEINDEX "tileindex.shp"
        TILEITEM "location"     
    END # Layer
```

And `'tileindex.shp'` has this content:

[image]

This is only a sample code that works with TimeManager, but it doesn't works with TemporalControler.

Is it possible to use this `'wms_timeformat'` with TemporalControler?

Answer (score -1):

Try playing with the Properties>Source settings. That seemed to make my layer magically work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @cefect! I have tried to set this option in QGIS but still doesn't work. I have add more details to my question. Maybe the problem is time format?